# How can I avoid generating multiple build files - angular 9 - ng build

Tags: angular, angular9

I have created a sample angular 9 application using angular cli and when I execute ng build, multiple files are generated to support different version of Browsers. (For Ex: main-es5.js and main-es2015.js).

As for micro-frontend architecture, I want to generate only one .js file by combing all of them for that i can upload it on server, how it can be done ?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Go to your `tsconfig.ts` and change `"target": "es2015"` to `"target": "es5"`

Comment: This definitely doesn't work